# How to get a json response from API to swagger UI

Tags: swagger, wso2-api-manager

I am implementing a swagger document for an existing API and the thing I can't work out is how to get the json response to show up in ***swagger-ui***. I am using ***Swagger 1.1***. My Json response is something like this.

```
"currentLocation": {
    "timestamp": "2015-12-10 07:12:38"
    "altitude": 34
    "longitude": 78
    "latitude": 44
    "accuracy": 1000
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using swagger 2.0? It already supports response models.

Comment: You need to share more of your definition.  Swagger 1.1 has been deprecated for some time, however it does support this feature.  Please post your spec

Answer (score 0):

Try the "description" field for supplying default values. For example,

```
currentLocation:
    type: object
    required:
      - timestamp
      - altitude
    properties:
      timestamp:
        type: string
        description: "2015-12-10 07:12:38"
      altitude:
        type: integer
        description: 34
```